# Can I override jekyll's config to set page or post specific encoding?

Tags: encoding, jekyll

I have some files that I would like to serve and most of them work out fine being displayed as UTF-8 but others only display properly in iso-8859-1.  I tried to just convert the file with `encode!("iso-8859-1", 'UTF-8')` since most iso-8859-1 characters are present in UTF-8 but I got `Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xE6" followed by "a" on UTF-8`

The file displays fine if I set `encoding: "iso-8859-1"` in `_config.yml` but then my UTF-8 files are messed up.  I tried setting `encoding:` and even `config.encoding` in my front matter but to no avail.